# I'm having trouble downloading TensorFlow Federated. I'm not sure which version of TensorFlow is compatible with TFF

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, matplotlib, scipy

[here are the versions of TFF, tensorflow and python which i'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4363.png)

I am encountering difficulties when attempting to run my script.py file. The issues stem from the incompatibility of various components, which is causing me considerable trouble. The root of the problem lies in the fact that the script requires a specific version of TensorFlow Federated (TFF), but I am unsure which version is compatible with my current setup. This uncertainty is leading to a series of errors and roadblocks that are impeding my progress.I am encountering difficulties when attempting to run my script.py file. The issues stem from the incompatibility of various components, which is causing me considerable trouble. The root of the problem lies in the fact that the script requires a specific version of TensorFlow Federated (TFF), but I am unsure which version is compatible with my current setup. This uncertainty is leading to a series of errors and roadblocks that are impeding my progress.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FES9N6i-5ThLxI_IFItPR24WaHEVKXWw?usp=drive_link
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NiwT.png)
above is the link to my FL implementation code with a requirements.txt file. I tried hard but still, my flModel.py file is not running could you please help me find out where the issue is in my code? How do I resolve the compatibility issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please replace the screenshot with plain text. Please add the commands you are running and the full error messages you're getting.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FES9N6i-5ThLxI_IFItPR24WaHEVKXWw?usp=drive_link
above is the link to my FL implementation code with a requirements.txt file. I tried hard but still, my flModel.py file is not running could you please help me find out where the issue is in my code? How do I resolve the compatibility issue?